# prove that the solution of $y=1-(1-\frac{c\cdot y}{k})^k$ is not less than $y=1-e^{-x\cdot y}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials

I have two equations $y=1-(1-\frac{x\cdot y}{k})^k$ and $y=1-e^{-x\cdot y}$, where $k$ is an integer such that $k\ge 2$, $y\in(0,1]$ and $1<x\le k$. By using the argument from [Prove the function $f(x)=1-x-(1-\frac{a}{n}x)^n$ has a real solution between $(0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501710/prove-the-function-fx-1-x-1-fracanxn-has-a-real-solution-between-0/501736#501736), I am able to show that both equations given above have solutions. Suppose that $y_1$ is a solution of $y=1-(1-\frac{x\cdot y}{k})^k$ and $y_2$ is a solution of $y=1-e^{-x\cdot y}$. I want to prove that $y_1\ge y_2$. I plot two functions [by wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y=1-%281-x/10*y%29%5E10%20and%20y=1-e%5E%28-x*y%29%20from%20x=1%20to%2010) for the case $k=10$ and it seems that the claim holds.

I found that under this setting, we have $1-(1-\frac{x\cdot y}{k})^k\ge 1-e^{-x\cdot y}$. I want to use this fact and try to prove by contradiction, but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Have you considered induction on $k$?

Comment: @Calvin Lin. I want $y_1,y_2$ to be the solutions. Sorry for the bad notations.

Comment: @Langma Yes, I interpreted it wrongly. Added a line in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (as you claim) that $1-(1-\frac{x\cdot y}{k})^k\ge 1-e^{-x\cdot y}$, then it follows that when these graphs intersect the line $y = 1- x$ which is decreasing, the graph on the left must intersect at a smaller $x$ value than the graph on the right, which means that $x_1 \leq x_2$.

Hence, $ y_1 \geq y_2$.